# xsl:when using Regex

Tags: xslt

I have a When clause that despite my best effort never returns true. I've tested the Regex using RegexBuddy and web sites and according to them the RegEx works.

```
                        <xsl:when
                        test="matches('LTHAB0113422/Cell:eNodeB Function Name=LTHAB0113422, Local Cell ID=0, Cell Name=LTHAB0113422-000-2100-1-1, eNodeB ID=113422, Cell FDD TDD indication=CELL_FDD', '^[A-Z0-9]+/Cell:eNodeB Function Name=[A-Z0-9]+, Local Cell ID=[0-9]+, Cell Name=.*, eNodeB ID=[0-9]+, Cell.*$')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'CELL'"/>
                    </xsl:when>
```

Comment: You may want to show desired input/output

Comment: The test you have posted DOES return `true` - so apparently your problem lies elsewhere.